# Creating dependency between Azure Datafactory Scheduled triggers

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have 2 scheduled triggers in Azure Data factory pipelines, lets say T1 and T2.
I want to have the trigger T2 to run after the trigger T1 is completed.
Does Azure Data factory has a mechanism to achieve the same for scheduled triggers?
Basically I want the Trigger T2 to start executing only after the trigger T1 is completed

Below is the more clear requirement

1)1st pipeline is starting at 10 AM and runs long till 11 AM

2)2nd pipeline is starting at 10.30 AM, so I need this 2nd pipeline to wait till the 1st one completes and even if the 1st one completes before 10.30, 2nd should start only at scheduled time of 10.30 not before that

Answer (score 1):

Use a Web Activity at the end of the 1st scheduled pipeline. That Web Activity will send a message to Event Grid which T2 is listening on, using the Event Grid trigger. Once that message is received, pipeline 2 will activate. Here's an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FpKrBLeqdj4

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the second the pipeline will be started immediately after completion of dependent pipeline, my requirement is as below
1)1st pipeline is starting at 10 AM and runs long till 11 AM
2)2nd pipeline is starting at 10.30 AM, so I need this 2nd pipeline to wait till the 1st one completes and even if the 1st one completes before 10.30, 2nd should start only at scheduled time of 10.30 not before that

Answer (score 1):

I was able to produce the expected coordination between pipelines by **using a look up in the second pipeline**, ie the 2nd pipeline will look for the file/result which should be put in a blob location when the 1stpipeline completes.

The lookup in the 2nd pipeline **should have no of retries with higher numbers (10 or 20)** and **retry interval every 30 mins**.
This will make the 2nd pipeline wait for the completion of 1st pipeline